# jsonを用いたAPIに関するコードを書きましたがエラーが発生します。

Tags: python, python3, json, api

自分では間違っているところを見つけられませんが、なぜかエラーが出てしまいます。
どなたかご教授ください。
因みに、これは「クラッシュロワイヤル」というゲームのAPIを使っています。

[Clash Royale API](https://developer.clashroyale.com/)

エラーコードは以下になります。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mto\Desktop\python_lesson\CRL\crl_api.py", line 53, in <module>
print(battle_info()[0]["type"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

実際のコード

```
import json
import requests

access_key = #ここでは省略しています

URL = 'https://api.clashroyale.com/v1'

def battle_info():
    target_api = URL + "/players/"
    playerTag = "%238QRCJQ9Y"
    url = target_api+playerTag+"/battlelog"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "max-age=60",
        "authorization": "Bearer  %s" % access_key}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    result = json.dumps(data,indent=4) 
    return result

print(battle_info()[0]["type"])
```

また、以下のbattle_info()を出力すると以下のようになります。

```
#実行コード
print(battle_info())
#実行結果
[
    {
        "type": "challenge",
        "battleTime": "20190509T081821.000Z"

　　　　#続きは省略
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/188751

Answer (score 3):

あなたの現在のコードでは、せっかくAPIで取得したレスポンスを`r.json()`でデコードしてpythonのList, Dictionaryに変換したもの(`data`)を`dump`で文字列に変更してしまっています。

つまりこんなことをやっているのと同じことです。

```
jsonText = '''\
[
    {
        "type": "challenge",
        "battleTime": "20190509T081821.000Z"
        ...
'''
print(jsonText[0]["type"])
```

`jsonText[0]`が最初の1文字`'['`を文字列として返しますので、その文字列に対して`["type"]`と言うインデックスを参照しようとしているので、*TypeError: string indices must be integers* なんてエラーになっています。

`battle_info()`の戻り値として`data`をそのまま返してみると良いでしょう。

```
def battle_info():
    target_api = URL + "/players/"
    playerTag = "%238QRCJQ9Y"
    url = target_api+playerTag+"/battlelog"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "max-age=60",
        "authorization": "Bearer  %s" % access_key}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data
```

お試しください。